# .htaccess: If any of these directories requested, rewrite to script and pass the requested dir as variariable

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a bunch of different blogs on my site i.e.

mysite.com/news
mysite.com/blog
mysite.com/bits
etc..

I use the same php script behind the scenes and want to keep the urls tidy so I've setup these rules:

```
# blogs
RewriteRule ^(bits|blog|news)(/?)$ news/?type=$1    
RewriteRule ^(bits|blog|news)/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/([0-9]+)(/?)$ news/article.php?type=$1&id=$2
```

Now what's happening is that the 'type' is always coming through as news? I don't see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding a leading '/' to the URL your are redirecting to - also you don't need to wrap the trailing '/' in parentheses.

Also, put a [L] flag at the end of the rule to stop it looking at the rest of the .htaccess

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(bits|blog|news)/?$ /news/?type=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(bits|blog|news)/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/([0-9]+)/?$ /news/article.php?type=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Prepending a RewriteCond of ..

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
```

.. to each rule will also filter out any chance of URL's with a query string being parsed.